# Android Studio work with module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

In my project I've got a main package and a module (app 2).

For the module, I use standard application -> import to project -> change it as library and make dependencies (`compile project(':app2')`).

Everything is ok but when I compile, it installs on my cell phone as two individual apps: "main app" and "app2" (which should be a module of main app).

Can anyone tell me how to correct this so that the full project will install as one app with module inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check all Manifest files and ensure your modules are not providing activity with `<intent-filter>` used by Lauchers:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

If it does, remove the `<intent-filter>` block. Also ensure your module's `build.gradle` uses `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` (as it should) and NOT `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`.